# A thesaurus with archaic and obsolete words

Tags: early-modern-english, resources, online-resources

Can you point me to any online thesaurus that contains obsolete, archaic, out-of-use synonyms for contemporary words?

Google search is horribly unhelpful, yielding hundreds common thesaurus and dictionary entries for the word *archaic*, usually in dictionaries that have been pruned of obsolete words.

Comment: A Dictionary of Archaic & Provincial Words, Obsolete Phrases, Proverbs & Ancient Customs, From the Fourteenth Century; Volumes 1 & 2

Comment: Single-word requests on EL&U should yield the kind of results you're looking for, too. :)

Comment: @Edwin: Available on Archive.org for download from Project Gutenberg. Very nice, thanks; Still, not a thesaurus :)

Comment: Hence not submitted as an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Comment: @MrHen: Actually, does the site's help center ever state resource questions are off-topic? I searched and found nothing like this, and this IS a "word choice" question, just indirect - in situation where direct questions would quickly tire out the user base ("What are some obsolete synonyms to [word]" is generally a poor question much better answered by a thesaurus than live people here.)

Comment: @SF. The community opinion periodically flip-flops on resource questions but it is my opinion is that all resource requests are inherently Too Broad.

Comment: @MrHen: The proof for that assertion would be an unending stream of answers to my question, with me being unable to objectively pick a single correct one from the flood, as all of them are correct, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: @SF. Not really. But if you want to continue this conversation we can head over to [chat]. :)