# Is there an historical thesaurus?

Tags: etymology, history, resources

Is there something like a thesaurus that offers terms more often used in the past?

For instance, *I beg you* would, in Shakespearean times, be *prithee*, while *chicks* during the 1920s would be *dolls*.

---

*Meta:* Seeing how the question on [a thesaurus with archaic and obsolete words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134848/a-thesaurus-with-archaic-and-obsolete-words) and several other thesaurus-related questions have been closed, I  fear this one might be, too. However, I am hoping it’s more on-topic. Please, if this must be closed, at least tell me where I should go to receive a good answer.

Comment: Were the comments to that question unsatisfactory?

Comment: Try the OED. It has 2.5 million example sentences, from the earliest written sources, grouped under headword. You can make your own thesaurus.

Comment: Is this Q better asked on meta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is! It's the Glasgow *Historical Thesaurus of English*, the world's only historical thesaurus. We published it through OUP in 2009 as the *Historical Thesaurus of the Oxford English Dictionary*, and is also freely available online at http://www.glasgow.ac.uk/thesaurus - we also provide a whole bunch of additional information and visualisations there, too.

We produced it at the University of Glasgow and it's the work of over 230 people, taking approximately 320,000 person-hours to complete – it began in 1965. I hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on John Lawler's comment on the OED. They did make rather expensive [historical thesaurus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199208999), which I myself own.

Comment: Guess you're not a "dasiberd"...

Comment: Nor a "doddypoll". / The [Historical Thesaurus of the OED](http://public.oed.com/historical-thesaurus-of-the-oed/) is also online (presumably subscribers only, but you may have access via your local library card).

Comment: Awesome! Just wish I had free access to it in the States